# How to execute files in Inno setup with multiple radio buttons?

Tags: inno-setup

How can I have file1.exe, file2.exe and file3.exe wrapped in a single setup file using Inno so that the file# of choice is launched when user selects its associated radio button?

Please see the complete script I'm trying to make work. Since there is no Check flag on [Files] or any kind of procedure and listeners, upon clicking Next - all 3 files launch one after another.

```
===

[Setup]   
CreateAppDir=no   
OutputDir=C:\Single-Exe   
OutputBaseFilename=setup   
Compression=lzma   
SolidCompression=yes   
DisableWelcomePage=True   
DisableReadyPage=True   
DisableFinishedPage=True   
Uninstallable=no

[Languages]
Name: english; MessagesFile: compiler:Default.isl

[Files]
Source: file1.exe; DestDir: {app};
Source: file2.exe; DestDir: {app};
Source: file3.exe; DestDir: {app};

[Run]
Filename: {app}\file1.exe; Flags: hidewizard runhidden 32bit; WorkingDir: {localappdata}
Filename: {app}\file2.exe; Flags: hidewizard runhidden 32bit; WorkingDir: {localappdata}
Filename: {app}\file3.exe; Flags: hidewizard runhidden 64bit; WorkingDir: {localappdata}

[Code]
const
  FileOneDesc =
    'Select if you want to run File1.exe';
  FileTwoDesc =
    'Select if you want to run File2.exe';
  FileThreeDesc =
    'Select if you want to run File3.exe';

var
  FileOneButton: TNewRadioButton;
  FileTwoButton: TNewRadioButton;
  FileThreeButton: TNewRadioButton;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var                                                 
  CustomPage: TWizardPage;
  FileOneDesclabel: TLabel;
  FileTwoDesclabel: TLabel;
  FileThreeDesclabel: TLabel;

begin
  CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Multiple executable pre-launch wizard', '');
  FileOneButton := TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm);
  FileOneButton.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  FileOneButton.Top := 16;     
  FileOneButton.Width := CustomPage.SurfaceWidth;
  FileOneButton.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  FileOneButton.Font.Size := 9;
  FileOneButton.Caption := 'Run File #1'
  FileOneDescLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  FileOneDescLabel.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  FileOneDescLabel.Left := 8;
  FileOneDescLabel.Top := FileOneButton.Top + FileOneButton.Height + 8;
  FileOneDescLabel.Width := CustomPage.SurfaceWidth;
  FileOneDescLabel.Height := 40;
  FileOneDescLabel.AutoSize := False;
  FileOneDescLabel.Wordwrap := True;
  FileOneDescLabel.Caption := FileOneDesc;

  FileTwoButton := TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm);
  FileTwoButton.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  FileTwoButton.Top := FileOneDesclabel.Top + FileOneDesclabel.Height + 8;
  FileTwoButton.Width := CustomPage.SurfaceWidth;
  FileTwoButton.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  FileTwoButton.Font.Size := 9;
  FileTwoButton.Caption := 'Run File #2'
  FileTwoDescLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  FileTwoDescLabel.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  FileTwoDescLabel.Left := 8;
  FileTwoDescLabel.Top := FileTwoButton.Top + FileTwoButton.Height + 8;
  FileTwoDescLabel.Width := CustomPage.SurfaceWidth;
  FileTwoDescLabel.Height := 40;
  FileTwoDescLabel.AutoSize := False;
  FileTwoDescLabel.Wordwrap := True;
  FileTwoDescLabel.Caption := FileTwoDesc;

  FileThreeButton := TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm);
  FileThreeButton.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  FileThreeButton.Top := FileTwoDesclabel.Top + FileTwoDesclabel.Height + 10;
  FileThreeButton.Width := CustomPage.SurfaceWidth;
  FileThreeButton.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  FileThreeButton.Font.Size := 9;
  FileThreeButton.Caption := 'Run File #3'
  FileThreeDescLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  FileThreeDescLabel.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  FileThreeDescLabel.Left := 8;
  FileThreeDescLabel.Top := FileThreeButton.Top + FileThreeButton.Height + 8;
  FileThreeDescLabel.Width := CustomPage.SurfaceWidth;
  FileThreeDescLabel.Height := 40;
  FileThreeDescLabel.AutoSize := False;
  FileThreeDescLabel.Wordwrap := True;
  FileThreeDescLabel.Caption := FileThreeDesc;
  end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`[Run]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection) section has [`Check`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck&anchor=Check) parameter like all the other sections whose entries are separated into parameters do. In your case I would write a common check function like this:

```
[Run]
Filename: {app}\file1.exe; Flags: hidewizard runhidden 32bit; WorkingDir: {localappdata}; Check: ShouldRunItem(1)
Filename: {app}\file2.exe; Flags: hidewizard runhidden 32bit; WorkingDir: {localappdata}; Check: ShouldRunItem(2)
Filename: {app}\file3.exe; Flags: hidewizard runhidden 64bit; WorkingDir: {localappdata}; Check: ShouldRunItem(3)
...

[Code]
function ShouldRunItem(Value: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  case Value of
    1: Result := FileOneButton.Checked;
    2: Result := FileTwoButton.Checked;
    3: Result := FileThreeButton.Checked;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Dear TLama - Thank you kindly for your time and assistance. Your function works perfectly for this project. Thanks to @RobeN as well.

Comment: Would also please advise how I could keep the Next button disabled at start-up and enable it once any one of the radio's are selected ?

Comment: You should ask this as a separate question, but I'll make an exception since you're new here and you've nicely formatted your code. You can do it e.g. [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/UNy305BS). Notice that I moved the `CustomPage` variable to the global scope to be available for the newly added `CurPageChanged` event method and added the `OnClick` event handler for radio buttons. The principle is simple. When the user enters your custom page and none of the radio buttons is checked, the next button is disabled. Enabled becomes only when the user clicks (selects) some of the radio buttons.

Comment: TLama, I truly appreciate you helping and particularly in explaining what is what, how and why in great detail.  Not only I'm new here, I am also new to Inno advanced, so I'm learning all around :) All the best!